# Como fazer imagem respeitar conteúdo da página

Tags: html, css

Consegui alinhar minha imagem através deste tópico [Alinhar texto depois de imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30057/alinhar-texto-depois-de-imagem)
, só que a imagem fica em cima de alguns outros conteúdos da página, como eu poderia arrumar?

**Minha div:**

```
<div width="10%" class="areaImagem">
    <?php 
        $id = $PDO->lastInsertId();
        echo  "<img src='imagens/". $id ."/".$user['foto']."' alt='Foto' width='30%' height='30%'/>"; ?>
</div>

<div class="areaTexto">
     <b>Título:</b> <?php echo $user['titulo'] ?> <br />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.areaImagem{
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.areaImagem img{
    width:400px;
}

.areaTexto{
    float:left;
    max-width:500px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Coloque um exemplo mais elaborado... Como podemos ajudar se nem o css temos?

Comment: só de você fazer .areaTexto{float:right; width: 90%;} já é para funcionar, você também está estilizando um paragrafo (p) que você nem tem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma div para ser a pai, no caso chamei de content, e adicione um display: inline-block; para quebrar para a próxima linha. segue um exemplo

```css
.areaImagem{
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.areaImagem img{
    width:300px;
}

.areaTexto{
    float:right;
    max-width:500px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.content{display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div width="10%" class="areaImagem">
     <img src='https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/105942/Free.jpg?sequence=1&isAllowed=y' alt='Foto' width='30%' height='30%'/>
  </div>

  <div class="areaTexto">
       <b>Título:</b> Titulo <br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div width="10%" class="areaImagem">
     <img src='https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/105942/Free.jpg?sequence=1&isAllowed=y' alt='Foto' width='30%' height='30%'/>
  </div>

  <div class="areaTexto">
       <b>Título:</b> Titulo <br />
  </div>
</div>
```